# Upload file with Powershell

Tags: powershell, file, http, curl, mime-types

I'm trying to create a command in Powershell that is an equivalent of

`curl -u username:abcd -i -F name=files -F filedata=@employees.csv https://myservice.com/v1/employees/csv`

I need to have file name in the request. So in Powershell

```
$FilePath = 'employees.csv'
$FieldName = 'employees.csv'
$ContentType = 'text/csv'
$username = "user"
$password = "..."

$FileStream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($filePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)
$FileHeader = [System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue]::new('form-data')
$FileHeader.Name = $FieldName
$FileHeader.FileName = Split-Path -leaf $FilePath
$FileContent = [System.Net.Http.StreamContent]::new($FileStream)
$FileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = $FileHeader
$FileContent.Headers.ContentType = [System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue]::Parse($ContentType)

$MultipartContent = [System.Net.Http.MultipartFormDataContent]::new()
$MultipartContent.Add($FileContent)

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$($username):$($password)" ))
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo" } -Body $MultipartContent -Method 'POST' -Uri 'https://myservice.com/v1/employees/csv'
```

Is there a better (shorter) way of doing this so I have a file name in Content Disposition?

```
$body = get-content employees.csv -raw
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("user:pass" ))
Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo" } -uri url -Method Post -body $body -ContentType 'text/csv
# a flag -ContentDispositionFileName would be great
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for `Invoke-RestMethod`.  You are doing so much extra work.

Comment: I have looked at the documentation, but I don't have enough Powershell-foo. I can see I could improve 2 things. Use -Credentials instead of -Headers (no idea how to create a Credential object). Use a file object with -Form to set the file name (same problem)

Answer (score 0):

Taking a guess with what your endpoint will accept, but here's an example of your `curl` request in `powershell`:

```
$u, $p = 'username', 'password'
$b64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("${u}:$p"))
$invokerestmethodParams = @{
    'Uri'             = 'https://myservice.com/v1/employees/csv'
    'Method'          = 'POST'
    'Headers'         = @{ Authorization = "Basic $b64" }
    'InFile'          = 'C:\path\to\employees.csv'
    'SessionVariable' = 's' # use $s to view content headers, etc.
}
$output = Invoke-RestMethod @invokerestmethodParams
```

Comment: Make a standard curl request is not an issue, but as I said I need a file name in ContentDisposition.

Comment: @LukaszMadon What do you mean `ContentDisposition`?  You didn't say that anywhere in your question.

Comment: "I need to have file name in the request." curl infers `filename` for `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="employees.csv"; filename="employees.csv"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition. In Powershell it seems I have to do whole `$FileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition` there is no flag.